How do I disable the annoying garbling of multiline comments in Common Lisp
In Common Lisp you can define multiline comments with #| \n\n\n |#.
However when I press Return with cursor above such comment, each line of the comment is appended with ' ;' and pressing Return multiple time can result in many ; ; ; ;.
;; aaa.lisp

(warn "beginning")






#|
                    ; ; ; ; ;
ala ma              ; ; ; ; ;
kota                ; ; ; ; ;
                    ; ; ; ; ;
|#

(warn "end")

That is very annoying.
I suspect the culprit is the code indicated below, but I do not know how to fix it. If there is no easy fix, do you suggest any alternatives?
emacs-31/lisp/newcomment.el::1117
(defun comment-add (arg)
  "Compute the number of extra comment starter characters.
\(Extra semicolons in Lisp mode, extra stars in C mode, etc.)
If ARG is non-nil, just follow ARG.
If the comment starter is multi-char, just follow ARG.
Otherwise obey `comment-add'."
  (if (and (null arg) (= (string-match "[ \t]*\\'" comment-start) 1))
      (* comment-add 1)
    (1- (prefix-numeric-value arg))))

Alternative
I can select a region and then press C-x r t for the command string-rectangle. The command asks me for the character, so I enter the comment characters ';;'. That gives me the same as the multiline comment but without the problem with garbling by adding the ; at column 40.
It's Paredit related problem
Commenting out these two lines hides the problem
https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/c4a2e859fe11a0d5731d2109ecf253d51b0301d0/personal/organised.el#L845
Minimal configuration
Starting Emacs with minimal configuration
https://github.com/bigos/Pyrulis/blob/master/Emacs/problem-with-paredit-garbling-multiline-comments.org#replicating-minimal-config
and trying to edit example Common Lisp file with multi line comment, still shows the problem.
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(unless (package-installed-p 'paredit)
  (package-install 'paredit))

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)

;; end of init.el -----------------------------


(fmakunbound 'comment-add) <- did not work

What do I have to do to try to reproduce the problem you are describing? Can you provide a recipe starting from emacs -Q?

It works fine with emacs -Q

https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/f6239430d12d062be9e43ff0f8b9e694c60b1a1b/modules/prelude-programming.el#L34 <- could that be a problem?

If it works fine with emacs -Q and it does not work fine when you load your init file, then bisect your init file to find the breakage.

I have verified init.el is correct. Now going through personal/organised.el

https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/c4a2e859fe11a0d5731d2109ecf253d51b0301d0/personal/organised.el#L845 <-- commenting out theses two lines removes the problem, so it must be paredit

pressing C-j does not have the problem, so it may be paredit-RET vs paredit-C-j

https://paredit.org/cgit/paredit/tree/paredit.el#n995 the suspect

It's good that you are able to debug the problem for yourself, but you should realize that the information you have provided is insufficient for anybody else to even start reproducing the problem. So all we can do is helplessly watch you try to figure it out for yourself but we cannot help (although occasionally somebody's crystal ball is clear enough to guide them to an inspired guess - but you cannot count on that). So you may be just jotting things down here as you go, but the question is probably useless for anybody else except for you.

The multi-line comment problem is annoying. But I may find a solution that will help others. I just needed a break, but I will keep looking. I may try to recreate a minimal config that illustrates the problem.

https://github.com/bigos/Pyrulis/blob/master/Emacs/problem-with-paredit-garbling-multiline-comments.org#replicating-minimal-config  I was able to replicate the problem with minimal configuaration, how do I turn it into a useful question?

Add the minimal configuration to your question so that the question becomes self-contained: that and the example file plus your description of what happens should be enough. I won't be able to do anything in the next week, but I'll try your instructions the week after and let you know. You might want to move your possible fix to an answer: if somebody provides a better answer, you can always accept the better one in the future.

Possible fix
Adding the following to my configuration seems to fix the problem. https://github.com/bigos/prelude/commit/69d16f230570e7e255bca9bd9550e088a5bd75ba
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "RET") nil)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") nil)))

It was inspired by the following line: https://paredit.org/cgit/paredit/tree/paredit.el#n118
